# How to write loops for field validation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why validation is always fails? Regular expressions should be fine, I guess the problem should be somewhere in `if(loginreg.test(login) && passwordreg.test(password) && repassword==password)`. Could someone please help me with it?

```
function CheckAuthData() {  
    var loginreg = /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{4,}\d$/g;
    var login = document.getElementById("login").value; 
    var passwordreg = 
        /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{1,}$/g;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var repassword = document.getElementById("repassword").value;    

    if(loginreg.test(login) && passwordreg.test(password) && repassword==password){         
        document.getElementById("labellogin").innerHTML = "";   
        document.getElementById("labelpassword").innerHTML = "";    
        document.getElementById("labelrepassword").innerHTML = "";      
        document.getElementById("pers_data").style.display = "block";       
    }

    if(!loginreg.test(login)){
        var label = document.getElementById("labellogin").innerHTML = "Login error!";
        document.getElementById("labellogin").style.color = "red";
    }   

    if(!passwordreg.test(password)){
        document.getElementById("labelpassword").innerHTML = "Password error!";
        document.getElementById("labelpassword").style.color = "red";
    }   

    if(repassword!=password){
        document.getElementById("labelrepassword").innerHTML =
            "Should be the same password!";
        document.getElementById("labelrepassword").style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting, and do you have any debugging info?

Comment: Check each condition separately to figure out which one fails.

Comment: You'll just have to walk through it with the debugger. While that code can be made a lot simpler, it's basically fine. So apparently the expressions aren't quite doing what you think they're doing. The problem isn't with the first `if` (although it is an anti-pattern to repeat the tests unnecessarily).

Comment: I debugged it, it always fails in - if(loginreg.test(login) && passwordreg.test(password) && repassword==password), even when the input data seems to be fine.
There is no message, it simply never passes the check...

Comment: **Update** oh wait, now it goes fine through the first if clause and goes to the next ones, except password equality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only actual *error* I can see there is that if any of those conditions fails *once*, you never clear the `red` off the element where it happened. But since you clear the text out of the element, it probably doesn't matter.

That said, testing the same conditions twice (in your first `if` and then again in subsequent ones, inverted) is a maintenance problem waiting to happen, as is all of the repeated code in the function.

You also don't need to recreate the regular expressions every time the function is called, and you don't need the `g` flag on them.

This addresses the various issues above *(note: I'm assuming this is contained in some kind of scoping function, so we're not creating new globals by moving those regexes out)*:

```
var loginreg = /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{4,}\d$/;
var passwordreg = 
        /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{1,}$/;
function CheckAuthData() {  
    var login = document.getElementById("login").value; 
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var repassword = document.getElementById("repassword").value;    
    var failed = false;

    updateField("labellogin", loginreg.test(login), "Login error!");
    updateField("labelpassword", passwordreg.test(password), "Password error!");
    updateField("labelrepassword", repassword == password, "Should be the same password!");

    if(!failed) {
        document.getElementById("pers_data").style.display = "block";       
    }

    function updateField(id, valid, message) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.innerHTML = valid ? "" : message;
        element.style.color = valid ? "" : "red";
        failed = failed || !valid;
    }
}
```

---

Made this a CW because...well...it probably doesn't actually answer the question, because there isn't enough info in the question. But hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: Magically, when I've putted regex outside of the function scope everything worked fine! Thank you very much for help!

Comment: @DarkAkira: It definitely wouldn't just be that. Glad this helped, though!